# tzdata freeze docker build Swfit image

Tags: swift, dockerfile

While run docker build to build a swift image, tzdata will stop the process.  It prompt to choose a location, but no reaction after I enter the number .

```sh
Configuring tzdata
------------------

    Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
Geographic area:
```

my Dockefile is :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
LABEL maintainer="Swift Infrastructure <swift-infrastructure@swift.org>"
LABEL Description="Docker Container for the Swift programming language"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    cmake \
    wget \
    ninja-build \
    clang \
    python \
    uuid-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    icu-devtools \
    libbsd-dev \
    libedit-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    swig \
    libpython-dev \
    libncurses5-dev \
    pkg-config \
    libblocksruntime-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    systemtap-sdt-dev \
    tzdata \
    rsync && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Vapor setup
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(wget -qO- https://apt.vapor.sh)"

# Install vapor and clean
RUN apt-get install swift vapor -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN vapor --help
```

It is work normally before I reset the Docker. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I also encountered this situation and I found solution from https://askubuntu.com/questions/909277/avoiding-user-interaction-with-tzdata-when-installing-certbot-in-a-docker-contai

Comment: @WeizhengLi Great！Works！Thanks！

Answer (score 3):

Prevent tzdata for asking by adding `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` to the `Dockerfile`.